# Drupal too high query time for query in drupal

Tags: mysql, database-performance

I'm have a drupal 7 site running onto the following server:

- Debian GNU/Linux 7.1
- 2 Intel core CPU
- 4Gb of RAM

I'm experimenting too high time for SQL query on it and a severe high load of the CPU when mysql queries are triggered from the site deployed.

For example the following query takes more than 20sec on average to provide data (run directly in the mysql console):

```
    SELECT DISTINCT node.nid AS nid, domain_source.domain_id AS domain_source_domain_id, field_data_field_date.delta AS field_data_field_date_delta, field_data_field_date.language AS field_data_field_date_language, field_data_field_date.bundle AS field_data_field_date_bundle, field_data_field_date.field_date_value AS field_data_field_date_field_date_value, field_data_field_date.field_date_value2 AS field_data_field_date_field_date_value2, field_data_field_date.field_date_rrule AS field_data_field_date_field_date_rrule, node.title AS node_title, node.language AS node_language, location.name AS location_name, 'node' AS field_data_field_date_node_entity_type, 'node' AS field_data_field_lieux_node_entity_type
FROM 
node node
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date field_data_field_date ON node.nid = field_data_field_date.entity_id AND (field_data_field_date.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_date.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN domain_source domain_source ON node.nid = domain_source.nid
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date field_data_field_date2 ON node.nid = field_data_field_date2.entity_id AND (field_data_field_date2.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_date2.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date field_data_field_date3 ON node.nid = field_data_field_date3.entity_id AND (field_data_field_date3.entity_type = 'node' AND field_data_field_date3.deleted = '0')
LEFT JOIN location_instance location_instance ON node.vid = location_instance.vid
LEFT JOIN location location ON location_instance.lid = location.lid
INNER JOIN node_access na ON na.nid = node.nid
WHERE (( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('activite', 'evenements')) AND (domain_source.domain_id NOT IN  ('6', '-5')) AND (DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE(field_data_field_date2.field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-01-15' OR DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE(field_data_field_date3.field_date_value2, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-01-15') )AND( (DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE(field_data_field_date.field_date_value, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-01-15') OR (DATE_FORMAT(ADDTIME(STR_TO_DATE(field_data_field_date.field_date_value2, '%Y-%m-%dT%T'), SEC_TO_TIME(3600)), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2014-01-15') ))AND(( (na.gid = '0') AND (na.realm = 'all') )OR( (na.gid = '0') AND (na.realm = 'domain_site') )OR( (na.gid = '6') AND (na.realm = 'domain_id') )OR( (na.gid = '1') AND (na.realm = 'view_unpublished_activite_content') )OR( (na.gid = '1') AND (na.realm = 'view_unpublished_image_d_ent_te_content') ))AND (na.grant_view >= '1') 
ORDER BY field_data_field_date_field_date_value ASC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET 0;
```

The size of the node table is <1000 rows as well as the field_data_date_value one.

The configuration of the my.cnf is the following:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
#
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user            = mysql
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir          = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 127.0.0.1
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer              = 128M
max_allowed_packet      = 256M
thread_stack            = 2M
thread_cache_size       = 8
join_buffer_size        = 2M

# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
max_connections        = 10
table_cache            = 1028
table_definition_cache  =1028
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit       = 8M
query_cache_size        = 128M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#
# Error logging goes to syslog due to /etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf.
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
log_slow_queries        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
long_query_time = 1
log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                        = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db           = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db       = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem
innodb_buffer_pool_size=512M
innodb_log_file_size=256M
innodb_log_buffer_size=5M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
innodb_thread_concurrency=8
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT


[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet      = 64M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer              = 64M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Is there a way to enhance the time of the query? what can be done? This decrease the site loading speed tremendously (as it's not the only slow query I've got...)

Thanks a lot

Comment: That is an enormous query to sort through; I'm not going to be able to manage it, sorry to say. It needs to be optimized. You probably should look up how to do queries on ranges of dates using index range scans.  Every time you do anything resembling `WHERE FUNCTION(column) = value` or something similar, you prevent MySQL from using indexes in the queries.

Comment: What kind of fields are `field_date_value[2]`?  You should never need to use STR_TO_DATE on a field that has the purpose of storing a date.  Or, conversely, if you need to use it, then you are storing your dates incorrectly.  If you store them correctly, you'll be able to do those comparisons many times faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I made several attempt at palying with it and if I remove the 2 left joins "LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date field_data_field_date2" and "LEFT JOIN field_data_field_date field_data_field_date3" and rename the variable into the where clause I drop to 0,04sec... which is far better... :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's a Views query, try turning on caching in the Views UI and see how that helps.